# C# Adding Program To Run Will Not Add Full Path

Tags: c#

There is something weird with the way I add to registry run.

When I use

```
 private static string AppPath = new Uri((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath;
```

to set the path in run registry it worked fine, but if folder name is "c#" for example the added key will be cut before # 
so should be :

c:/desktop/c#/myprogram.exe
but it's

c:/desktop/c

What's the problem can you guys help?

Comment: maybe you could give up for the "#" character..

Comment: @socksocket this is just a tiny problem what if it doesn't work with many more symbols? I need a solution to a problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is an issue with the Uri escape symbols. Try this:

```
string AppPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().Location;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't duplicate what you're seeing. I think maybe you're missing some information:

```
var uri = new Uri("c:/desktop/c#/myprogram.exe");
string raw = uri.ToString(); // "file:///c:/desktop/c%23/myprogram.exe"
string local = uri.LocalPath; // "c:\desktop\c#\myprogram.exe"
```

Are you sure about what's coming out of the Codebase property there?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `#` character gets encoded in the `Uri` and becomes `%23` instead.

I'm not sure why you want to use `Uri` to get the location of the executable. There is a better way (as **nightsnaker** posted).

However, if you **must** use an `Uri` (for whatever reason), you can get the full path by doing something like this:

```
        string s = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        Uri u = new Uri(s);
        string local = u2.LocalPath+u2.Fragment.Replace('/','\\');
```